# Converting png to pdf with imagemagick: how to set the resolution?

Tags: pdf, conversion, imagemagick, dpi

I have an image `foo.png` which is 1240 * 1754 pixels.

Using imagemagick on OS X, I convert this to a .pdf and specify the resolution to be 150 dots per inch, so its physical format will be exactly an A4 sheet:

`convert -units PixelsPerInch -density 150 foo.png bar.pdf`

However, if I now check the resolution of the resulting file:

`identify -verbosy bar.pdf | grep Resolution`

it says:

`Resolution: 72x72`

Note: the image should *not* be scaled or resized or anything. It's 1240 * 1754 and should stay that way. I just want to make sure the PDF covers exactly one full A4 sheet, which is the case with these pixel dimensions at 150 dpi.

How do I make sure the resulting .pdf file has the right resolution?

(Edit) Come to think of it, I realize that perhaps a PDF document (even if it's just a single page) doesn't necessarily have one overall dots per inch or resolution setting.
In this case I'm creating a PDF out of one image, but in general, a PDF can contain many elements, possibly all with different resolutions.

So I'm wondering, maybe with my approach I'm only setting the dpi for just this image, but the `Resolution` that is reported by `identify -verbose bar.pdf` is something else entirely?

Comment: Open the page in Acrobat Pro, and then use the Object Inspector, which is part of the Print Production tools.

Comment: @MaxWyss Thanks, but unfortunately I don't have Acrobat.

Answer (score 2):

When converting from image to pdf, lowering the **density** improves the resolution.

```
convert -units PixelsPerInch -density 72 foo.png bar.pdf
```

On the other hand, when converting from pdf to print quality image, the **density** should be high.

```
convert -units PixelsPerInch -density 600 bar.pdf foo.png
```

I could not find any documentation for this though.

(This is an old question. Hopefully, it will help those who are still looking for an answer.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
convert foo.png -page A4 bar.pdf
```

Comment: Same result, unfortunately. It still says `Reslution: 72x72`. I noticed that the output of `identify -verbose bar.pdf` also shows: `Geometry: 595x842+0+0` and `Page geometry: 595x842+0+0` (both with your command as well as mine). Not sure what that means?

Comment: Does your image fit into A4 page this method or your method?

Comment: I'm not sure, how do I check? By looking at the `identify -verbose` result, the Geometry doesn't like anything related to A4, and neither does the 72x72 resolution.

Answer (score 0):

the native DEFAULT resolution  of a PDF is 72 points per inch thus a 1" x 1" image of one dot per point will be arguably 72dpi but that's not the way it should be counted its  pixels of 72 wide by 72 high at a placement scaled to 1" square.

So the original is 1240 wide 1754 high and to be applied to 210 mm x 297 mm so its roughly 6.095 dots per mm horizontal and 5.905 dots per mm vertical (not a very useful description).

The target is A4 scale at a desired density of 150 dots per inch that's in PDF terms an image 1,240.157 dots wide by 1,753.937 high at a true scale of 72 points per inch.

We can not have sub pixels so its rounded to 1240 x 1754 @ 72 x 72 ptpi Thus also not a sensible description but accurate

It will be more sensible if we add @ 150 pxpi (as a nominal pixel density) and most images in PDF will use those units in hdpi and vdpi or x-ppi y-ppi terms such as

```
--0000.ppm: page=1 width=1800 height=682 hdpi=599.67 vdpi=599.12 colorspace=DeviceRGB bpc=8
--0001.ppm: page=3 width=1834 height=665 hdpi=345.93 vdpi=345.75 colorspace=DeviceRGB bpc=8
```

or

```
>pdfimages -list tt.pdf
page   num  type   width height color comp bpc  enc interp  object ID x-ppi y-ppi size ratio
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1     0 image     950   575  gray    1   8  image  no        27  0    72    72 42.4K 7.9%
   1     1 image     950   575  index   1   8  image  no        19  0    72    72 2454B 0.4%
```